# jquery ui tabs load after all htm is rendered

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

im using jquery ui tabs.

sometimes when my page loads, all the html for each tab is displayed on the page, then it takes a bit of time before the tabs appear and html is positioned within the tabs. from a ui point of view this initial flicker is quite annoying.. is there a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are waiting for html to render, thats why you use `$(document).ready()` or the shorthand for it.

What you can do is under the tab section (html) you should put

`<script>$('#tab').tab()</script>`//or .tabs() cnt remember

then it would do it on the fly, mind you the jQuery core file should be on head section :)

Comment: btw i know its dirty and un practical but thats the only way i can think of that could tabulate it the fastest way possible :)

Answer (score 2):

Because the right way to embed jquery is the use the

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  ...
}
```

jQuery will be executed when all the page have finished loading. This is 100% intended.

One trick you can use, is to add some JS, still using jQuery but outside the function
    $(document).ready(function(){
      ...
    }

```
// Class indicating that JS is enabled                                                                                                                                           
$('html').addClass('js');
```

Then, get the closest CSS class next to the things you don't want to flicker, and add some CSS

```
/**
 * For anything you want to hide on page load when JS is enabled, so
 * that you can use the JS to control visibility and avoid flicker.                                                                                                                                         
 */
html.js .myClass {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, of course, you'll need to handle the visibility of .myClass with some JS, to display it against what we have defined in the CSS rule.

This will `display: none` the flickering stuff as fast as you won't be able to see it flickering.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem.
I declared the tabs "display: none;" in my css.
When jQuery.tab() fire it should render correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One not-so-good approach is to set a 100% height and width overlay with z-index to hide everything of your page until all the ui rendering is done.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be modify to the secondary tabs (those who does not appear first) the z-index property and in the callback put the original value back again.